# Пункт в трудовом договоре программиста

Tags: работа

Работаю программистом, в трудовом договоре стоит пункт

> программист обязан закончить все начатые проекты или выплатить работадателю штраф.

Никаких документов кроме ТК не подписывал, то есть нет подтверждения что я занимался этими проектами (кроме переписки по электронной почте в виде списка исправлений)

Такая информация может быть подтверждением работы над проектом?

Comment: > программист обязан закончить все начатые проекты

Пишете заявление, 2 недели и "давай до свидания". Если будут зажимать трудовую книжку - за эти дни простоя можно еще и деньги отсудить будет.

Трудовой договор не может ограничивать права работника по отношению к тому, что прописано в ТК РФ. 

А проекты работодатель может заканчивать очень долго (как я понял, в вашем случае нет техзаданий/спецификаций).

Answer (score 6):

Бред. Согласно ТК РФ, обязанность работника по выплате штрафных санкций возникает в случае схождения всех параметров:

1. Если это напрямую указано в действующем трудовом контракте
2. Причинения реального материального ущерба
3. Если работодатель это доказал

В вашем случае 2-й и 3-й пункты не проходят. Если только работодатель не применит лазейку под названием "Возмещение затрат связанных с обучением работника" ст. 249 ТК РФ.

В любом случае работодатель не имеет права штрафовать на сумму более одного месячного заработка - все что свыше через суд.

В вашем случае, не демонизируя работодателя, я бы все таки крепко задумался: по понятиям вы правы или работодатель? Закон законом, но человеческие отношения никто не отменял.

Answer (score 2):

да ето бред) Вы должны что-то работадателю пока у вас заключен договор, как только вы его засторгаете, какие-либо обязательства (кроме выплат задолженностей, компенсация со стороны работадателя) заканчиваются. По действующему закондотельсву вы можете расторгнуть договор, но скорее всего 2 недели вы должны будетет отработать. 
Это так сказать по закону.

По человечески - решать вам, выполнять то что подписали даже если ето ущемляет ваши права или нет.

Comment: Согласен с тобой

Answer (score 2):

На вашем месте я бы показал договор юристу, вышеуказанное конечно правильно, но только по отношению к трудовому договору. А у вас может быть например контракт на выполнение работ (каковые определяются в спецификации ака техзадание). Или другая какая то гадость.

P.S. Хотя, если вы отдали трудовую, скорее всего никаких таких сложностей не должно возникнуть.